# Kivy align Switch left in BoxLayout

Tags: python, switch-statement, position, kivy, alignment

I want to align a switch to the left side of a BoxLayout. For labels i achieved this with the following code:

```
text_size: self.size
```

This places my label text on the bottom-left corner of my boxlayout. However, i cant manage to do the same with a **switch widget**. I tried playing around with size_hint_x, size, pos and so on, but i cant align the elements properly without disturbing the sizes of the boxes.
Currently my labels are aligned properly, so i tried assigning ids to them and orientating the switch according to the current pos of the label with the following:

```
BoxLayout:
    padding: 100, 0, 0, 0
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    text_size: self.size
    valign: 'middle'
    Label:
        text: 'this is already correctly aligned'
        id: 'labelCorrectlyAligned'
#Some other code
BoxLayout:
    padding: 100, 0, 0, 0
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    #here i need something like text_size: self.size but for switches
    Switch:
        size_hint_x: labelCorrectlyAligned.pos[0] #this should be the current X-position of the label
        #pos_hint_x: labelCorrectlyAligned.pos[0] #didnt work either
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: For convenience, i created a dynamic class for my left-aligned switch:

```
<SwitchL@Switch>:
    size_hint_x: None
    size: 83, self.height
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can just set the `size` of the `Switch` to its minimum as noted in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.switch.html):

> The minimum size required is 83x32 pixels

Any size bigger than that will just have the 83 by 32 image centered in that larger size.

Also, in these layout situations, I find it helpful to color the backgrounds of `Widgets` to easily see exactly where they are and how big they are. Here is a modified version of your 'kv` that does both of the above suggestions:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        padding: 100, 0, 0, 0
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,0,0,1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label:
            text: 'this is already correctly aligned'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'
            id: 'labelCorrectlyAligned'
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,1,0,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

# Some other code

    BoxLayout:
        padding: 100, 0, 0, 0
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,1,0,1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Switch:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 83, 32
            on_active: app.setBluetoothConnection(self)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,0,1,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
```

Of course, when you are satisfied with the layout, just remove the `canvas.before:` blocks.

By the way, the `text_size` and `valign` have no effect in the `BoxLayout`, they must be in the `Label` rule.

So, both the `Switch` and the `Label` are on the left of the `BoxLayout`. A common way to size a `Label` is to use:

```
size_hint: None, None
size: self.texture_size
```

This gives you the minimum size for a `Label`.

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks! That makes it so easy and clean, before i had to wrap around stuff with placeholder boxes and stuff. Thank you!